# Satellite moving target tracking simulation

Tags: references, satellite, simulation

I am trying to create a Simulation of an earth-pointing satellite.
The satellite should track a moving target on the ground via an on-board camera.

How can I calculate the goal attitude of the satellite?

I assume I have every data needed.
XY Point in image,
Camera data (FOV...)
Rotation and transformation of the satellite...

I am especially interested in detailed literature for this topic.
Till now I only found papers explaining control algorithms, but
no explanation of getting the goal attitude.

Another idea would be, to control the satellite's attitude by the target XY pixel offset
from the middle of the picture. I am not sure if this is possible. I couldn't find any
literature about it.

Comment: You can try to find documents about the VividX2 satellite that shoots the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OBxJSroyTcI